# Docker based tomcat webapp fails only on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, docker

We have dockerized our webapp. The app was working as expected on all platforms - linux, mac etc.

Recently it started failing only on Mac. The webapp fails to start because of weird NoClassDefFound/NoSuchMethodError kind of exceptions.

```
api     | Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ReadOnlyThreadContextMap;
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createDefaultInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:83)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataInjectorFactory.createInjector(ContextDataInjectorFactory.java:67)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.ContextMapLookup.<init>(ContextMapLookup.java:34)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:117)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:125)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:77)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:171)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:145)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:70)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:57)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
api     |   at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
```

The same docker image when started on Centos works perfectly fine.

We are completely clueless of this behavior. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Docker Version on Mac

Version:      17.09.0-ce
API version:  1.32

Docker version on Centos

Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24

Comment: The method `getThreadContextMap()` was added in version 2.8. So this error means that you somehow got a version 2.7 or earlier log4j on your classpath, possibly before the 2.8 or higher version.

Comment: Are you building the image separately on each host?

Comment: @Matt  Same image pulled from docker repo.

Comment: @Erwin Thanks for pointing that out. Looks like that's the problem but it doesn't explain how it's working when deployed in Docker inside Linux but rightfully failing when deployed in Docker on Mac. I wasn't convinced that would have been the problem because its working on all our test envs except on my macbook. That's pretty weird!

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to look at your setup. One difference is that MacOS file systems are case-insensitive by default so if you put `lOg4J-2.7.JaR` in your classpath, and the file is `log4j-2.7.jar`, then on Linux it won't find it but on a MacOS FS without default settings it will find it. But that's just a wild guess

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Docker for Mac run's containers in a Linux VM so native mac fs isn't involved much, maybe a little when you map volumes from the mac > vm > container.

Comment: @AnilG that's impressive then!  One difference is Centos will probably be using a loopback devicemapper storage driver. Recent Docker for Mac will be using overlay2. You might be hitting an edge case where layers aren't being merged properly and a jar file is missing? Try comparing the file systems you are presented in the container on each OS.

Comment: @Matt Same no. of jars in classpath in both cases. And the behavior is consistently seen on many macbooks.

Comment: Do you actually have different log4j jar files in the containers on mac/centos then, as Erwin suggested?

Comment: Yes @Matt. Erwin's assessment was accurate. I did have the incompatible log4j 2.5 and 2.8 versions in classpath. Its all packaged inside war inside tomcat on centos based docker image.